# PLS-00302: component 'DEP_DET' must be declared - Why am i not able to fetch details

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 Declare
     Type Dep_Rec_Typ Is Record ( Dep_Id    Number
                        , DEP_NAME  VARCHAR2(30)
                    );
     Type Dep1 Is Table Of Dep_Rec_Typ;                       
     Type Emp_Rec_Typ Is Record ( Employee_Id   Number(6)
                        , First_Name    Varchar2(20)
                        , Last_Name Varchar2(25)
                        , Email Varchar2(25)
                        , Dep_Id    Number
                        );
     Type Emp_Tt Is Table Of  Emp_Rec_Typ;
     Type Class_Grp Is Record ( Dep_Det Dep_Rec_Typ
                       , Emp_Dt Emp_Tt 
                       );

     Type Class_Tt Is Table Of Class_Grp;                            
     class_det Class_Tt;
  Begin
     Select  Dep_Id,Dep_Name
     bulk collect into class_det.Dep_Det
     From T_Dep; 
  end;
```

Error
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 23, column 30:
PLS-00302: component 'DEP_DET' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 24, column 2:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 21, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here.? why do you need so many types,records  and collections? . If you are certain about what you want to do , there would a simpler solution than what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have a multilevel collection with first column is a record type and second is a table type.  Type Class_Grp Is Record ( Dep_Det Dep_Rec_Typ
                       , Emp_Dt Emp_Tt 
                       );     I have to fetch data in to table of the above type. Could you please let me know how to go about writing a query for the same

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use bulk collect with that kind of construction, but you can do is easily with a loop.

```
   cursor cu_t is
     Select  Dep_Id,Dep_Name
     From T_Dep;

     i number;
Begin
     i := 1;
    for rec in cu_t loop
       class_det(i).Dep_Det := rec;
       -- dbms_output.put_line( class_det(i).Dep_Det.Dep_Id||' '|| class_det(i).Dep_Det.Dep_name);
       i := i + 1;
   end loop;
end;
```